# Error in Retrieving Year Month Date from Calender object

Tags: java, date

All this is my program where i am trying the folowing

**Below is my code for Dates functionality...**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class DateToCalender {
public static void main(String args[]){
//String strFormat="yyyymmdd";

//DateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormat);
DateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
df.setLenient(false);
Calendar start=Calendar.getInstance();
try {
Date fromDt =(Date)df.parse("20111207");
//Date myDate = new Date();
//myDate = (Date)myDateFormat.parse("20111207");
//myGDate.setTime(myDate);
start.setTime(fromDt);

                start.set(Calendar.MONTH,(start.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));
System.out.println(start);

System.out.println(start.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println(start.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1);
System.out.println(start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
//System.out.println("From My class"+myGDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));

//System.out.println("From My class new month"+(myGDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));

} catch (ParseException e) {
System.out.println("Invalid Date Parser Exception ");
e.printStackTrace();
}
} 
}
```

when iam executing this code iam getting folowwing o/p

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA
=1,YEAR=2011,MONTH=12,WEEK_OF_YEAR=50,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=7,DAY_OF_YEAR=341,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
2011
0
7
```

**
 **issue is :**

```
Though iam entering date as 2011/12/07
            I am getting     year as 2011
                             month as 0
                             date as 7
Can some one help in resolving above issue
```

Could any body please let me know , how this can be resolved .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't subtract 1 from the month; `Calendar` already knows that it's zero-based.

It seems to me like you're doing far too much work here.  Why can't you just do this?

```
private static final DateFormat DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT;

static {
    DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT.setLenient(false);
}



public Calendar getCalendar(String dateAsString) {
    Calendar value = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date d = DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT.parse(dateAsString);
    value.setTime(d);
    return value;
}
```

There's an exception that needs to be added to the method signature, but you get the idea.  Look at the `Calendar` javadocs.  This could be easier.

Comment: System.out.println(start.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1).this is typo error actually statement is System.out.println(start.get(Calendar.MONTH)) .and iam getting o/p as 2012 month as  0

Answer (score 0):

setting a condition to check the month can resolve your problem:

```
try {    
Date fromDt =(Date)df.parse("20131209");
start.setTime(fromDt);
start.set(Calendar.MONTH,(start.get(Calendar.MONTH)));
int month = start.get((Calendar.MONTH));
if (month ==11){    
System.out.println(start.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println(start.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
System.out.println(start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}else{
start.set(Calendar.MONTH,(start.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1);   
System.out.println(start.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println(start.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println(start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
}
```

this will print out :

2013

12

9

Comment: Though i did in the same format iam getting year 2012 month 0 date 7 for the date 2011/12/07

Comment: ya tried with the year 2011 month 12 date 07 . Iam getting o/p as Year 2012 Month 0 date 7